# No access to Internet nor localhost when connected to OpenVPN vpn on Ubuntu 20

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

On **Ubuntu 20** I have received and client.ovpn file and I tried connecting using the following command

```
sudo openvpn --config ~/Download/client.ovpn
```

but that didn't work because I couldn't connect to the website which was behind the VPN. Actually, I couldn't resolve the DNS of that protected server.

Then I went to Activities -> Network -> Under VPN .> Import from file. I imported the client.ovpn file and connected to VPN successfully and I can access the protected website I was supposed to. But now I cannot access anything else on the Internet not my server on localhost.

I went through the Internet looking for solution but I just cannot get it to work. And to make things worse, I'm not good with networking setup and VPNs.

Here is the `ip route` before connecting to VPN and after if that helps.

Before connecting to VPN

```
➜  ~ ip route                          
default via 192.168.100.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp0s20f3 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-9d2526679794 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.100.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.4 metric 600
```

After connecting to VPN

```
➜  ~ ip route
default via 10.200.136.1 dev tun1 proto static metric 50 
default via 192.168.100.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.200.136.1 dev tun1 proto static metric 50 
10.200.136.0/21 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 10.200.142.215 metric 50 
35.161.223.96 via 192.168.100.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto static metric 600 
140.100.0.0/23 via 10.200.136.1 dev tun1 proto static metric 50 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp0s20f3 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-9d2526679794 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.100.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.4 metric 600 
192.168.100.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto static scope link metric 600
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. I can access the internet but not my localhost when connected to my company VPN. Did you find a solution?